# Connect to database through two ssh tunnels in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: database, intellij-idea, ssh, datasource, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to add a postgresql database as a datasource in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.
I've worked with a datasource through ONE ssh tunnel already. But now the database server is behind a firewall which only accepts ssh connections from a management server. The only way to access the db server goes over the management server.

So I (or IntelliJ) have to connect via ssh to this server and then, by using another user, tunnel via ssh to the database server.

Everything clear? :-D

The problem is, that IntelliJ offers only to configure one ssh tunnel. But after the first tunnel I need to use a second one, to finally connect to the database server...
Any Ideas?

Thx in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a [local port forward](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Local_Port_Forwarding) using OpenSSH or any similar tool which will forward `127.0.0.1:2222` to `firewall:22` via the Management Server, then use IntelliJ IDEA tunnel configuration to `127.0.0.1:2222` like you would do with the single tunnel.

`ssh -L 127.0.0.1:2222:firewall:22 <management server>`

You can configure an [External Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) to automate this process. On Windows machine I had great experience with [Bitvise SSH Client](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download) for creating tunnels/port forwards and starting them automatically.

Comment: Thx. The firewall has no real address (hardware), the connections just go through it. So if I do a port forward for my localhost to the management server, I'm only there, but not on the db server? Where or how to address the ssh connection to the database server itself?

Comment: Then you just port forward through the management server to the database server and connect to the database as localhost which will get forwarded to the database server via the management server and the firewall.

Comment: So I have to add the port forward on the management server, right?

Comment: Yes, from what you've described it seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` supports your scenario out of the box. The trick is to create two entries in your `~/.ssh/config` file for the management server, one for `your-user` and one for `special-user`. Then use `ProxyJump` to chain your connections together.

So, start by setting up a `Host` section for the management server and the user your are connecting to from your local machine:

```
Host mgmt
    HostName management.server.com
    User your-user
    ...
```

Then, set up a `Host` for the user on the management server that you will be logging in as:

```
Host mgmt-special-user
    HostName management.server.com
    User special-user
```

To this same host, add a directive to tell `ssh` to create a tunnel to your DB:

```
    LocalForward <free-port-on-your-box> <db-ip-or-host>:<db-port>
```

Then tell `ssh` that this host can be reached from the first host:

```
    ProxyJump mgmt
```

You can now `ssh mgmt-special-user` from your local machine. `ssh` will automatically jump through the `mgmt` host, and will also automatically extend the tunnel through `mgmt` and back to your local machine.

`ProxyJump` (`-J`) was added in OpenSSH 7.3 (released in 2016).